# jQuery and AJAX: how to deal with too fast responses?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've done a web page that has to make the use wait a loooong time before getting the answer.

When the user clicks on "Generate" (complex stuff), i do a slow slideUp() of the main div and immediately after that, I launch my "background" AJAX call:

```
$('#div-lol-generate-result').slideUp(4000);
$('#div-lol-generate-form').slideUp(3000);
$.ajax({
    url: '/long/api/call/that/takes/between/1/and/10/seconds',
    data: data,
    dataType: 'json',
    method: 'POST'
})
.done(function(result) {
    console.log('ok :');
    console.log(result);
    var monp=$('<p />');
    if (typeof(result.error)!='undefined') {
        for (var i in result.error) {
            monp.append(result.error[i]);
            monp.append('<br />');
        }
    } else if (typeof(result.story)!='undefined') {
        console.log(result.story.length);
        for (var i in result.story) {
            monp.append(result.story[i]);
            monp.append('<br />');
        }
    }
    monp.last().remove();
    $('#div-lol-generate-result').empty().append(monp).slideDown();
    });
})
.error(function(result) {
    console.log('Erreur :');
    console.log(result);
})".
```

Everything works fine... *only when the answer takes longer* than the "hide" animation. If the answer is fast, the we can see the content of the maindiv being replaced.

How do you deal with that?

Comment: You can use `setTimeout` to postpone the results show

Comment: Alternatively, perform the AJAX call after `.slideUp()` is done, i.e. as a callback.

Comment: @Terry That's exactly what I dont want to do! :) I want the user to wait and doing a 'slide' makes "waiting time" feel a lot shorter!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You make sure both the animation and the ajax call has completed before you replace the content

```
var promise1 = $('#maindiv').slideUp(4000).promise();

var promise2 = $.ajax({
                   url      : '/complexstuff',
                   data     : data,
                   dataType : 'json',
                   method   : 'POST'
               });

$.when.apply($, [promise1, promise2]).done(function(elem, data) {
    $('#maindiv').html(data.result).slideDown();
});
```

This way the ajax call starts right away without having to wait for a callback, and the promises makes sure both have completed before the callback for `$.when` is called.

Comment: I'll try that, but I feel like the `$.ajax()` will instant return like it already does now,.. so this means it'll only wait for the slideUp to finish. And this may only work for fast answers. For long answers, I'm pretty sure it doesn't work, but I'll give it a try... and the most annoying stuff: I have to fill `$('#maindiv')` with the result of the AJAX call. How to deal with it here? Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: Uhm, it's a direct replacement for the code you posted, it just waits for the element to be hidden, and the ajax call to complete, before it replaces the content and slides the element back down.

Comment: It should be noted that if your server takes 4 seconds to answer requests, you're doing something wrong, and should be optimizing the serverside scripts as well.

Comment: I'm asking for a distant API that only accept one request every second, and I sometimes (not all the time) need to do *up to 10 requests*, so this might takes up to 10 seconds. When you said it waits for ajax call to complete, does it wait for the lauch to be complete, or for the total AJAX call (including callbacks to `.done()` and `.always()`)?

Comment: Why not just try it and see, replace the code you have with the one in the answer above and see what happens. If you keep the `done` callback the way you have it in your code, you might as well not bother to do it this way, as it won't change anything.

Comment: It doesn't work, so I've put my whole source code in my question so you can see all my code.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion, I've learned a lot about Deferred and now I understand my code. Thus I check your answer as the good one, because you've put me on the right track, but I'll answer to show you the code I ended up with (sorry for my english, I hope you understand what I mean...)

Answer (score 0):

Here's my final working code, thanks to adeneo

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#div-lol-generate-result').hide();
    var sub=function() { return lol_submit(); };
    var lol_submit = function() {
        var data=$('#lol-generate-form').serialize();
        $('#lol-generate-form :input')
            .prop('disabled', 'disabled');
        $('#lol-generate')
            .unbind('click')
            .click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
            });
        $.when(
            $('#div-lol-generate-result').slideUp(4000),
            $('#div-lol-generate-form').slideUp(3000),
            $.ajax({
                url: '/lol/json/story',
                data: data,
                dataType: 'json',
                method: 'POST'
            })
        )
        .then(function(a, b, c) {
            result=c[0];
            var monp=$('<p />');
            if (typeof(result.error)!='undefined') {
                for (var i in result.error) {
                    monp.append(result.error[i]);
                    monp.append('<br />');
                }
            }
            else if (typeof(result.story)!='undefined') {
                console.log(result.story.length);
                for (var i in result.story) {
                    monp.append(result.story[i]);
                    monp.append('<br />');
                }
            }
            monp.last().remove();
            $('#div-lol-generate-result')
                .empty()
                .append(monp)
                .slideDown();
        }, function(a, b, c) {
            /* should never happen
             * TODO: hide and all ask refresh
             */
            // a=xhr
            // b='failure'
            // c='Not Found'
        })
        .always(function(result) {
            $('#lol-generate-form :input').removeAttr('disabled');
            $('#lol-generate').click(sub);
            $('#lol-generate-form-input-summoner-name').focus().select();
            $('#div-lol-generate-form').slideDown();
        });
        return false;
    }
    $('#lol-generate-form').submit(sub);
    $('#lol-generate').click(sub);
});
```